# R Random Sample looping

Tags: r, loops

I have some code which gives me a random sample from my data set. I want to create a loop now which takes a random sample of `5K` a `100 times` and inserts the samples into one table with a flag for each of the `100 samples`.

I used the below code for 1 sample:

```
sampxx <- sm_fin_all3[sample(1:nrow(sm_fin_all3), 5000, replace=FALSE),]
```

I have tried a few things which haven't worked. Any help will be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `replicate` to create 100 samples

```
replicate(100, sample(1:nrow(sm_fin_all3), 5000, replace=FALSE))
```

---

If we need a flag or index to indicate the sample, then, use the `simplify=FALSE` argument of `replicate` to return as a `list`, set the names of the `list` elements with the sequence (1:100) and if necessary, use `stack` to return a two column data.frame where one column indicates the index.

```
stack(setNames(replicate(100, sample(1:nrow(sm_fin_all3), 
              5000, replace=FALSE), simplify = FALSE), 1:100))
```

---

If we need to subset the dataset, create the `list` of sampled rows, loop through the sequence of `list`, subset the 'sm_fin_all3' based on the rowindex from 'lst' and then create a new column of 'ind'

```
lst <- setNames(replicate(100, sample(1:nrow(sm_fin_all3), 
              5000, replace=FALSE), simplify = FALSE), 1:100)
lapply(seq_along(lst), function(i) transform(sm_fin_all3[lst[[i]], ], ind = i))
```

Comment: thanks for that guys. How do I keep all the variables in my data set when taking the samples using the code above?  Thanks

Comment: @S.Kohli It is not clear how you wanted the output.  Is it to subset the dataset for each sample?

Comment: Sorry, I want to keep all the variables when I create my samples. So my final output will have all my variables and a flag which indicates which record is in which sample. Some records could possibly be in multiple samples. Hope that makes it clearer. Thanks

Comment: @SKohli  Updated the post.  Please check if this makes sense

Comment: I ran the code below   lst <- setNames(replicate(100, sample(1:nrow(sm_fin_all3), 
                                      5000, replace=FALSE), simplify = FALSE), 1:100)

sampx2 = lapply(seq_along(lst), function(i) transform(sm_fin_all3[lst[[i]], ], ind = i))

dep <- as.data.frame(sampx2)

sqldf(" select ind, count(*)
      from dep
      ")                    I was expecting there to be 500,000 records in my final output table sampx2. It seems when you create lst it contains 500K, but am I missing a step in the second part of the code? I should get 500K in my final output.

Comment: @SKohli  `sampx2` is still a `list` of `data.frames`.  you need `dep <- do.call(rbind, sampx2)`

Comment: Thanks alot for your help mate